# How to set a single ComboBoxCell in a TextBoxCell column of DataGridView?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I have a `DataGridView` with two columns defined like:

```
Dim col As New DataGridViewColumn
col.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(&HFFAAAAAA)
col.Name = "Description"
col.MinimumWidth = 80
col.DataPropertyName = "Description"
col.ValueType = GetType(String)
col.ReadOnly = True
col.CellTemplate = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
S0Grid.Columns.Add(col)

col = New DataGridViewColumn
col.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(&HFFBBBBBB)
col.Name = "Value"
col.MinimumWidth = 80
col.DataPropertyName = "Value"
col.ValueType = GetType(String)
col.CellTemplate = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
S0Grid.Columns.Add(col)
```

I need that the cell in position Col=1, Row=0 is a `ComboBox` and not a `TextBox`. So I tried to add the following code but it does not work, the edit control remains a TextBox.

```
Dim cbCell As New
DataGridViewComboBoxCell
cbCell.Items.AddRange([Enum].GetNames(GetType(System.Reflection.BindingFlags)))
S0Grid(1, 0) = cbCell
```

Do you know how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

That code should work, is it possible that it's not getting called or that it throws or similar?

Try this code:

```
Dim cbCell As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell
S0Grid(1, 0) = cbCell
MessageBox.Show("Test")
```

Do you see the messagebox? And do you see the combo now?

Comment: thank you for the interest. I verified and the code is executed, maybe some other setting interfer with my implementation. I will do additional checks